# Supporting both SQL Server and Oracle in an EF DB first scenario

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm involved in a project which uses Entity Framework + database-first + SQL Server. There has been a decision that application has to support Oracle as well without changing the code base.

So my idea for a basic prototype is the following: whenever the SQL Server DB changes

- migrate changes to Oracle
- generate EDMX files from both DBs
- use T4 to set the connection string and the EDMX which is used with the code base

Is this ok? Is it there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is more of a matter of taste, than what's right and wrong.
as long as it functions correctly in your testing - you're good.

Although - it is important to remember that EF was not meant to allow changing data sources without modifying code.
Therefore - I think there is a basic problem with the requirement.
I would say - either use OLEDB/ODBC which was meant exactly for that, with all queries in configuration files, or expect to change code with DBMS engine change.

Remember that the data types that exist in the DBMS are different, and for example - the Oracle BLOB is not as the MSSQL binary...

So - I would say two things:
1. If the code pass your tests, and your hapy with the results - the technique you use is working.
2. Fit the technology you use to your requirements.. EF does not fit your requirement as a base technology. ODBC/OLEDB do.